# Tangent bundle of a compact two-dimensional manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles

- For which (connected) two dimensional compact manifold M, oriented or not, the tangent bundle TM is trivial?
- For which of these manifolds the complexified tangent bundle $T^\mathbb{C}M = TM\otimes \mathbb{C}$ is trivial?

Comment: For your first question: note that trivial tangent bundle 
 is the definition of parallelizable. And parallelizable manifolds are always orientable. Finally, a geometry argument gives the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429608/which-compact-orientable-surfaces-are-parallelizable

Comment: I have rolled this back to the original version because the original version had an accepted answer before someone made a revision. If someone believes there is an interesting refinement of this question that deserves further attention, then I recommend that they ask that question themselves as a new question, which can then get its own answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an almost complete answer. I start with a summary of the different cases. In all the cases $M$ is assumed to be a closed 2-manifold.

1. $M$ is orientable. Then $TM$ is trivial if and only if $M$ is the torus (genus 1).
   Proof: Euler characteristic $+$ Poincaré-Hopf theorem.
2. $M$ is orientable. Then $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is trivial if and only if $M$ is the torus (genus 1).
   Proof: $c_1$ is equal to the Euler characteristic times 2.
3. $M$ is non-orientable. Then $TM$ is not trivial. The trivial bundles are orientable.
4. $M$ is non-orientable. If $M$ is not the Klein bottle, then $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is not trivial.
   Proof: Consider a covering of $M$ with an oriented manifold, and pull the bundle back.

Remaining case: $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ of the Klein bottle. I don't know whether it is trivial or not.

**Details:**

Let's start with the closed orientable manifolds. In this case
$TM$ is trivial if and only if $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is trivial if and only if $M$ is the torus $T^2$.

Proof: Let $M$ be the $k$-fold connected sum of the torus $T^2$. The Euler characteristic of $M$ is $\chi(M)=2-2k$. By Poincaré-Hopf theorem the Euler characteristic of a closed orientable manifold is equal to the Euler number of its tangent bundle: $\chi(M)=e(TM)$. Here $e(TM)$ is defined as the sum of the indices of any generic tangent vector field, i.e. any continuous section of the tangent bundle. Therefore $TM$ admits a nowhere zero section if and only if $k=1$. Hence $TM$ is nontrivial if $k \neq 0$, and we know that the tangent bundle of the torus is trivial ($T^2=S^1 \times S^1$ and $TS^1$ is trivial.)

The complexified bundle is $TM \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong TM \oplus TM$. $TM$ can be endowed with a complex structure, whose first Chern class number $c_1 (TM)[M]=e(TM)$. Therefore $c_1(TM \oplus TM)=2 \cdot c_1(TM) $ is zero if and only if $k=1$, i.e. when $M$ is the torus.

The tangent bundle $TM$ of a closed nonorientable manifold $M$ is nonorientable. Therefore it cannot be trivial. Its first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1(TM)$ is nonzero.

In the case of the complexified tangent bunde $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ of a nonorientable manifold $M$ the first Stiefel-Whitney class of the complexification does not help. Indeed, it is $w_1(TM \otimes \mathbb{C})=w_1(TM \oplus TM)=2 \cdot w_1(TM)=0$, since $w_1(TM) \in H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$. (According to the fact that every complex bundle is oriented.)

Instead, consider a $k$-fold covering $p: N \to M$ of the non-orientable manifold $M$ with an oriented one $N$. Such a positive integer $k$ and covering $p$ always exists. Then $p^*(TM) \cong TN$ and $p^*(TM \otimes \mathbb{C}) \cong TN \otimes \mathbb{C} $. Therefore if $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is trivial, then $TN \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is trivial as well, which implies that $N$ is the torus.

On the other hand $k \cdot \chi(M)= \chi(N)$ is zero if $N$ is the torus. Hence the triviality of the bundle $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ implies that $\chi(M)=0$, that is, $M$ is the Klein bottle.

We proved that $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is nontrivial, if the nonorientable manifold $M$ is not the Klein bottle. I don't know that the complexification of the tangent bundle $TK \otimes \mathbb{C}$ of the Klein bottle $K$ is trivial or not.

Comment: I think $TK\otimes\mathbb{C}$ is non-trivial, although I haven't checked the computations. Note that $TK\cong \eta\oplus\mathbb{R}$ where $\eta$ is a line bundle over $K$ classified by $w_1(\eta)\in H^1(K;\mathbb{Z}/2)$. Complexification preserves direct sums, so the only question is whether the complexificaition of $\eta$ is trivial. This depends only on whether $c_1(\eta\otimes\mathbb{C})=\beta(w_1(\eta))\in H^2(K;\mathbb{Z})$ is non-trivial, i.e. whether $w_1(\eta)$ is the reduction of an integral class.

Comment: I don't agree with your statement 2. In general, if $E$ is the complexification of a real bundle, then it satisfies $2 c_k(E) =0$ for $k$ odd (see e.g. p.173-174 of Milnor-Stasheff). For a closed orientable surface, this implies that $c_1(E) =0$, and therefore that $E$ is trivial (since it splits as a line bundle plus a trivial bundle).

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

- Mark: do you mean that $w_1(\eta)$ of a real bundle $\eta$ is the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-reduction of the complexification $\eta \otimes \mathbb{C}$? Why is it true? Or maybe I misunderstood, could you explain your final sentence? Thank you.

- Dominique: Then what is the mistake in my argument?

Comment: The isomorphism $TM \otimes\mathbb{C} \cong TM \oplus TM$ in your argument should instead be $TM \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong TM \oplus \overline{TM}$. It corresponds to the splitting of $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ into the $+i$ and $-i$ eigenspaces of the endomorphism coming from the complex structure of $TM$.

Comment: Thank you. My isomorphism holds as isomorphism of real bundles, but it's not an isomorphism of complex bundles. 

Therefore my argument about $TM \otimes \mathbb{C} $ is completely wrong. Then what do you thing about the complexification of the tangent bundles, are they trivial or not? And why? 

Now I have an idea: comnsider $c_2(TM \otimes \mathbb{C} )$. Is it the squere of $\chi (M)$?

Comment: The result is that $TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is trivial iff $\chi(M)$ is even. In the orientable case, this follows from my comment above. In the non-orientable case, a short computation shows that $c_1(TM \otimes \mathbb{C}) \mod 2 = w_1(M)^2$. For surfaces, it turns out that $w_1(M)^2 =w_2(M)$. (This follows from the Wu formula, or the fact that it's true for $\mathbb{R}P^2$...)